# Css - background-img url no-repeat center center Not working

Tags: html, css

i using bootstrap in my website but just i get one problem

-HTML

```
 <div class="first-background">
        ----- skip 
 </div>

 <div class="second-background">
        ----- skip
 </div>
```

-CSS

```
.first-background{
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E8ECEE;    
}

.second-background{
  background-image: url(../img/background.png);

  -- first ways
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

  -- second ways
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;

  -- third ways 
  background-image: url(../img/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
```

}

i tried anyways but cover or center center Not Working in my webSite

how to solve this problem? now i don't have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your syntax for the 2nd div is incorrect. Specifically, you spelled 'class' wrong. Usually stack overflow does not take kindly to these types of issues, so make sure the code you post is almost the EXACT code (minus raw data) into the question.